# How to use the GraphQL Get query from aws in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, aws-appsync, aws-amplify

I'm trying to make use of the getquery for graphql in react.js. But I can't figure out how to go about doing this. I already succeeded to use the list query.

```
state = { patients: [] }

async componentDidMount() {
  try {
    const apiData = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(listxxxx))
    const patie = apiData.data.listxxxx.items
    this.setState({ patie })
    console.log(patie)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq ', err)
  }
}
```

How does one go about using the get query? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an ID to retrieve an item with any get query. getPatient(id:"YOUR ID HERE"){}`

Something like...

```
query Get_Patient_By_Id{
  getPatient(id:"2dbcb870-e302-4ed5-a419-68751597129c"){
     id        
     name
  }
}
```

For React, you'll add in the id to the variables list argument:

```
const getPatient = await API.graphql(
  graphqlOperation(
    queries.getPatient, 
    {id: "2dbcb870-e302-4ed5-a419-68751597129c"}
  )
);
console.log(getPatient.data.getPatient);
```

docs: https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/api#simple-query